# Android SimpleDateFormat parses wrong

Tags: android, sqlite, simpledateformat

I am having a date parse problem. In my app I retrieve new comments from our server. The retrieved epoch long timestamps are correct, but when I try to save them to the sqlite db sometimes the last comments parses the date wrong.

SimpleDateFormat:

```
this.dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
this.dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Parsing:

```
Log.v("GET COMMENT TIME A", ""+cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time")));
try {
    Log.v("GET COMMENT TIME B",""+dateFormat.parse(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time"))));
    c.setCreation_time(dateFormat.parse(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time"))));
    Log.v("GET COMMENT TIME C", ""+c.getCreation_time());
} catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Logcat:
previous comments parsed GOOD

```
01-13 13:01:58.009: V/GET COMMENT TIME A(10536): 2013-01-13 12:01:37
01-13 13:01:58.017: V/GET COMMENT TIME B(10536): Sun Jan 13 13:01:37 CET 2013
01-13 13:01:58.017: V/GET COMMENT TIME C(10536): Sun Jan 13 13:01:37 CET 2013
```

Logcat:
last comment parsed WRONG:

```
01-13 13:01:58.064: V/GET COMMENT TIME A(10536): 2013-01-13 12:01:41
01-13 13:01:58.064: V/GET COMMENT TIME B(10536): Sun Jan 13 13:01:41 CET 2013
01-13 13:01:58.064: V/GET COMMENT TIME C(10536): Tue Jan 01 13:01:41 CET 2013
```

So when you look at logcat GET COMMENT TIME B and C, you can see that

```
dateFormat.parse(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time")))
```

first returns a corrected parsed time and 1 line further it parses another wrong time? Or why does the getCreation_time() return a wrongly parsed date sometimes?

edit:
the comment just has getter ans setters

```
public Date getCreation_time() {
    return creation_time;
}

public void setCreation_time(Date creationTime) {
    this.creation_time = creationTime;
}
```

Comment: Strange behavior, but can you isolate the problem by letting your creationTime getter/setter handle `String`s (not `Date`s), then just set it to `cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time")` and let your dateFormat parse that stored string?

Answer (score 3):

So, parsing 2 times the exact same `String` sometimes gives different results ? The only reason I can think of is that the `SimpleDateFormat` [is not threadsafe](http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html). 
Is it frequent ? What happens if you use a variable instead of an instance field ?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); 
Log.v("GET COMMENT TIME A", ""+cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time")));
try {
    Log.v("GET COMMENT TIME B",""+dateFormat.parse(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time"))));
    c.setCreation_time(dateFormat.parse(cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("creation_time"))));
    Log.v("GET COMMENT TIME C", ""+c.getCreation_time());
} catch (ParseException e) {}
```

Comment: aha, this could be it, gonne check this

Comment: after using the threadsafe SimpleDateFormat the problem hasn't  reoccured on to this day so I am accepting this answer. Thx!